# Firefox styling form completely differently

Tags: css, forms, firefox

I'm having a bit of trouble with FireFox (on Mac, I'm assuming Windows is the same). Basically, I'm making a to-do list web app and the form you fill out with your todo works fine on every browser I've tested so far, apart from FireFox.

The height of my text-boxes are taller, my submit button says "Submit Query" for some reason, my urgent button (styled the same) has a different height & width to that of the submit button. And, when either of the buttons are clicked, it jumps back up to the 'landing' section of the page.

The link to the page is: [to-do-today.com](http://to-do-today.com)

Here's the HTML for the form:

```
<form id="to-do-form" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<div class="form-text-fields">
    <input type="text" name="title" id="td-title" class="text-input" required="required" 
    title="Enter your to-do" value="What do you need to do?" onClick="selectAll('td-title');" />

    <input type="text" name="description" id="td-description" class="text-input" 
    title="Enter your description" onClick="selectAll('td-description');" value="Need a description?" />
</div>

<div class="form-buttons">
    <input type="checkbox" name="urgent" id="urgent" title="Urgent?" class="check-box"/>
    <div class="button check-box-button" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">   
    <label class="check-box-label" for="urgent">Urgent?</label>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" class="button button-margin" />
</div>  
</form>
```

And here's the CSS that's controlling it:

```
form {
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto 10px;
}
.form-text-fields {
float: left;
width: 84%;
}
.form-buttons {
float: right;
width: 14%;
margin-right: 1%
}
.text-input {
width: 100%;
height: 25px;
float: left;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.23);
border-radius: 3px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
color: #a6a6a6;
background-color: #fff;
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", 
             Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 300;
font-size: .9em;
}
.button {
width: 100%;
height: 25px;
margin-right: 1%;
padding: 5px;
float: right;
font-family: "adelle"; 
font-weight: bold;
font-size: .9em;
text-transform: uppercase;
line-height: .9em;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #945000;
color: #fffefc;
background-color: #ffb258;
border: 1px solid #9f5908;
border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-appearance: none; /*stops default styling of buttons on iOS and Andriod.*/
-moz-appearance: none;
}
.button:hover {
background-color: #e19033;
border: 1px solid #804b0a;
-moz-transition: .1s ease-in; -webkit-transition: .1s ease-in; -o-transition: .1s ease-in;
}
.button:focus {
background-color: #1ccc13;
border: 1px solid #10800a;
-moz-transition: .1s ease-in; -webkit-transition: .1s ease-in; -o-transition: .1s ease-in;
}
.check-box {
position: absolute;
top: -9999px;
left: -9999px;
}
.check-box-label {
height: 25px;
min-width: 100%;
color: #797879;
display: block;
text-align: center;
color: #fffefc;
}
.check-box:checked ~ .check-box-button {
background-color: #9d1878;
/*background-color: #c67110 !important;*/
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px #750055;
}
```

Any ideas why FireFox isn't liking this form?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox ain't liking this form because it doesn't parse `box-sizing`. For now, you need to use the vendor-specific one on your `global.css`:

```
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, labels aren't buttons. Buttons (and some input elements) are buttons. Semantics and web standards aside, how the label and the input apply your padding (on class button) is quite different. The input puts the padding inside the assigned height of 25px. The label puts it on top of the height. (So the height is much larger than 25px.) Also, your text will be centred vertically in the label if you add a line-height of 25px.

Comment: Ah, I had no idea labels and inputs handle padding differently! Yea, because I'm using the check-box hack on the urgent button (label element) I can't use the same input type as on the submit button.

Any ideas why FireFox gives "Submit Query" as the text for the submit input?

Comment: Yes, you haven't specified a value for the value attribute. Use value="whatever" to set the text for the input to whatever. Btw, grab Firebug (a Firefox add-on). It is extremely helpful for troubleshooting code.